# Group different counted values in a single row

Tags: mysql, sql

Sql fidle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06f573/9).

```
SELECT UserId,totalLikes FROM Users 
LEFT JOIN(select ownerId, PostId from Posts) a ON ownerId = UserId
LEFT JOIN(select idOfPost, count(idOfPost) AS totalLikes from Likes) b ON idOfPost = PostId
WHERE UserId = 120 GROUP BY UserId
```

This is a simplified part of the query that i am using, on the fiddle it works exactly how i need it to, it counts every `idOfPost` as a like for every post that belongs to the user specified, in this case `where UserId = 120`
and it groups the result in a single row.

But when i run this in `WAMP` i am getting the following error `#1140 this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` witch i think is because i need to group by `PostId` as well, but if i do  that i get multiple rows, naturally because the id of the posts are different but i want to have it in a single row.

So my questions are: Should i disable the `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` witch i'm not really sure what impact would have, or is my tables structure at fault and it needs to be changed, maybe including the `UserId` in the `Likes` table, or my query is at fault and needs to be changed?

*mysql version 5.7.14 on WAMP*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` in the subquery and `sum()` aggregate in the main query:

```
SELECT UserId, sum(totalLikes) AS totalLikes
FROM Users 
LEFT JOIN Posts a ON ownerId = UserId
LEFT JOIN (
    select idOfPost, count(idOfPost) AS totalLikes 
    from Likes
    group by idOfPost) b ON idOfPost = PostId
WHERE UserId = 120 
GROUP BY UserId
```

[SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06f573/23)